# is it possible to return new observable inside operator, nested observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs

```js
var url = "http://domain.com/some/url";
// this endpoint will return websocket URL

Rx.DOM.ajax({
  url: url,
  method: 'GET',
  responseType: 'json'
}).scan(function(o, data) {
  // data.websocker is websocker url
  return Rx.DOM.fromWebSocket(data.websocket_url, null, function(o) {
    console.log(o);
  }, function(o) {
    console.log(o);
  });
}).subscribe(function(data) {
  // Success Message
  console.log(data);
}, function(error) {
  // Log the error
  console.log(error);
});
```

As shown in above example. is it possible to send the Observable from inside the operators like promises ?

Comment: Why would it not be? They are javascript objects, like any others. However, what use case are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure this is quite common and there are alot of operators that exist to process inner observables in various ways.  In this example, you might use `flatMap` instead of `scan`:

```
var url = "http://domain.com/some/url";
// this endpoint will return websocket URL

Rx.DOM.ajax({
  url: url,
  method: 'GET',
  responseType: 'json'
}).flatMap(function (data) {
  // data.websocker is websocker url
  return Rx.DOM.fromWebSocket(data.websocket_url, null, function(o) {
    console.log(o);
  }, function(o) {
    console.log(o);
  });
}).subscribe(function(data) {
  // will receive messages that are received from the websocket
  console.log(data);
}, function(error) {
  // Log the error
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: is this supported by all the operators or only specific ones ?

Comment: Only specific operators. Most of the XxxMap varieties is a good place to start.